# how to remove port from x-forwarded-for header in azure webapp?

Tags: azure, joomla, azure-web-app-service

I have a Joomla app on azure's WebApp on Linux.
I want to get the client ip in order to be able to block by ip with the Admin Tools extension.
The admin tools has an option to get the client ip from the x-forwarded-for header, the problem azure is adding a random port to the client ip by so making blocking impossible.
How can I get rid of the port?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Application Gateway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-gateway/features#rewrite-http-headers